# Error( Does not have companion object and too many arguments for public constructor adapterState(listState List,stateData>)

Tags: kotlin, filter, android-recyclerview, data-class

I am new in programming. I have problem with the error above for filter.

I am getting error shown below. I have tried for a few weeks but still have no idea how to solve it.

> Too many arguments for public constructor adapterState(listState: List) defined in com.e.shoppingmallfooddrink.adapterState

Please help me.

Thank you very much.

Main activity

```
package com.e.shoppingmallfooddrink

import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var viewAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<*>
    private lateinit var viewManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
    private lateinit var stateSearch: EditText

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    stateSearch = findViewById(R.id.stateSearch)
    viewManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2)
    viewAdapter = adapterState(stateFlag.listState)
    recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycleViewState).apply {
        // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
        setHasFixedSize(true)
        // use a linear layout manager
        layoutManager= viewManager
        // specify an viewAdapter (see also next example)
        adapter = viewAdapter
    }
    addTextListener()
}

private fun addTextListener() {
    stateSearch.addTextChangedListener( object: TextWatcher{
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            var s=s.toString().toLowerCase()
            data class filteredList (var name: String, var photo: String)
            for (i in 0 until stateFlag.listState.size) {
                val text: String = stateFlag.listState[i].name
                if (text.contains(s)) {
                    filteredList(stateFlag.listState[i].name,stateFlag.listState[i].photo)
                }
            }
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity))
            viewAdapter = adapterState(filteredList, this@MainActivity)
            recyclerView.setAdapter(viewAdapter)
            viewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() // data set changed
        }
    }
    )
}
}
```

Adapter

```
package com.e.shoppingmallfooddrink

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.grid_view_state.view.*

class adapterState (val listState:List<stateData>):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<adapterState.MyViewHolder>()
    {
        inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            fun setDataState(listDM: stateData){
                Glide.with(itemView.context)
                    .load(listDM.photo)
                    .into(itemView.listPhotoState)
                itemView.listTextState.text = listDM.name
            }
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val listState = listState[position]
            holder.setDataState(listState)
        }

        override fun getItemCount() = listState.size

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
            val textView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.grid_view_state, parent, false)
            return MyViewHolder(textView)
        }
    }
```

Data class

```
package com.e.shoppingmallfooddrink

data class stateData (var name: String, var photo: String)

object stateFlag {
    val listState = listOf<stateData>(
        stateData("Selangor","https://www.crwflags.com/fotw/images/m/my-selan.gif"),
        stateData("Kuala Lumpur","https://www.crwflags.com/fotw/images/m/my-kl.gif"),
        stateData("Malacca","https://www.crwflags.com/fotw/images/m/my-melak.gif"),
        stateData("Johor","https://www.crwflags.com/fotw/images/m/my-01.gif"),
        stateData("Penang", "https://www.crwflags.com/fotw/images/m/my-p.gif"),
        stateData("Pahang","https://www.crwflags.com/fotw/images/m/my-pahan.gif"),
        stateData("Kedah","https://www.crwflags.com/fotw/images/m/my-kd.gif"),
        stateData("Kelantan","https://www.crwflags.com/fotw/images/m/my-kelan.gif"),
        stateData("Negeri Sembilan","https://www.crwflags.com/fotw/images/m/my-neger.gif"),
        stateData("Perak","https://www.crwflags.com/fotw/images/m/my-perak.gif"),
        stateData("Perlis","https://www.crwflags.com/fotw/images/m/my-perli.gif"),
        stateData("Sabah","https://www.crwflags.com/fotw/images/m/my-sabah.gif"),
        stateData("Sarawak","https://www.crwflags.com/fotw/images/m/my-saraw.gif"),
        stateData("Trengganu","https://www.crwflags.com/fotw/images/m/my-teren.gif"),
        stateData("Putrajaya","https://www.crwflags.com/fotw/images/m/my-pj.gif"),
        stateData("Labuan","https://www.crwflags.com/fotw/images/m/my-la.gif")
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error gives the exact issue. `Too many arguments for public constructor adapterState(listState: List)`. The construtor takes only one argument

```
class adapterState (val listState:List<stateData>)
```

but you are passing two arguments:

```
viewAdapter = adapterState(filteredList, this@MainActivity)
```

Remove `this@MainActivity` argument.

Comment: It solve one of my problem. But I still having another problem for filtered list. Is it because this method of writing is for array not data class?

Comment: what is the second problem? if it is not related you can add another question to SO

Comment: The error as below\MainActivity.kt: (51, 44): Classifier 'filteredList' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here